# Add matrices with different dimensions and labels

Tags: python, matrix, pandas, padding, dimensions

I have 2D labeled matrices using the [larry](http://berkeleyanalytics.com/la/work.html#creating-a-larry) package for python with possibly different dimensions , I need to add them with the labels aligned . The larry package takes care of this but expects same dimensions for addition of two matrices.

But for my task each dimension has different labels in different order. larry handles it while adding

e.g:

`la.add(lar1, lar2, join='inner')`

but expects both lar1 and lar2 be of the same dimensions , but my matrices may even have different dimensions in addition to different ordering of the labels.

example of what I want:

```
ADD([[1,2][3,4]],[[5,6,7][5,7,2]],label=[[A,B,C][X,Y]])
```

Should result in an output with maximum dimensions, padding missing dimensions with zero while adding.

Can pandas package accomplish the above task, one may give an answer using pandas too?
[This link explains](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html#basics-binop) that pandas has align functions and reindex functions to accomplish the above , but how to accomplish addition with automatic re-dimensioning and alignment, favoring the maximum dimensions?

Comment: What do you expect the answer to be? And is this valid Larry code?

Comment: @AndyHayden  No example is what I want

Comment: Can you give a small, self-contained working example. The `ADD(...)` will raise exceptions for multiple reasons.

Comment: @PhillipCloud I got the solution , do add as answer how to do the same thing using pandas

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` overrides arithmetic operators to do exactly what you want. Currently, there's no option to control the index joining. They do an outer join by default:

```
In [39]: a = DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('CD'), index=list('AB'))

In [40]: b = DataFrame([[1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8]], columns=list('CDY'), index=list('ABX'))

In [41]: a + b
Out[41]:
    C   D   Y
A   2   4 NaN
B   4   7 NaN
X NaN NaN NaN
```

There's [an open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1094) about this.

Comment: both the matrices have different label ordering , will it work , does it automatically align the labels following the order:outer, right, inner join for overlaps and conflicts?

Comment: What are the labels in each dimension?

Comment: each dimension has different labels in different order. larry handles it while adding e.g la.add(lar1, lar2, join='inner') but expects both lar1 and lar2 be of the same dimensions

Comment: @PhillipCloud you can use fill_value argument, which is possibly what OP wanted: `df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer without resorting to pandas but still interested to know how the same can be accomplished in pandas,The solution is to use the outer Join:

```
>>>a=larry([[1,2],[3,4]],label=[['A','B'],['C','D']])

>>> b=larry([[1,2,5],[1,3,4],[6,7,8]],label=[['A','B','X'],['C','D','Y']])
>>> a
label_0
    A
    B
label_1
    C
    D
x
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> c=la.add(a,b)
>>> c
label_0
    A
    B
label_1
    C
    D
x
array([[2, 4],
       [4, 7]])
>>> c=la.add(a,b,join='outer')
>>> c
label_0
    A
    B
    X
label_1
    C
    D
    Y
x
array([[  2.,   4.,  nan],
       [  4.,   7.,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan]])




>>> c=la.add(a,b,join='outer',missone=0)
>>> c
label_0
    A
    B
    X
label_1
    C
    D
    Y
x
array([[ 2.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 4.,  7.,  4.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.]])
>>> a
label_0
    A
    B
label_1
    C
    D
x
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> b
label_0
    A
    B
    X
label_1
    C
    D
    Y
x
array([[1, 2, 5],
       [1, 3, 4],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>>
```